# vba scraping nested (?) tab/button

Tags: vba, ms-access, web-scraping

I've been trying to scrape an intranet site at work longer than I'm willing to admit. The program is Agile (a common manufacturing tool) which uses IE so the address doesn't change while navigating. The tab/button/menu I want to select is inside a tab_wrapper which I am not able to get to with my skill set.

The furthest I can drill down is...

```
idoc.getElementById("rightPaneContent").getElementsByTagName("Form")(0)
```

...but it doesn't show a complete result for DIV, LI or A.

The menu drop down I'm trying to select is actually redundant, but the menu bar uses HREF javascript without class or ID which I also tried to execute without any luck, so I turned my attention to the drop down menu with ID's.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

    Dim page, srch As String
    
    srch = Me.txtSearch
    page = "http://xxagile.xxxxxx.com/Agile/" & _
           "PLMServlet?module=LoginHandler&opcode=forwardToMainMenu#"
           
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer: Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
    
        With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate page
        End With
    
        Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        
    Dim iDoc As HTMLDocument: Set iDoc = ie.Document
    
        With iDoc
        .getElementById("toggle_search_menu").Click        ' select menu
        .getElementById("cls_901").Click                   ' select ITEM from menu
        .getElementById("quicksearch_string").Value = srch ' enter string
        .getElementById("top_simpleSearch").Click          ' click search button
        End With
        
        Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    
    'iDoc.getElementById("rightMenuImg").Click ' error 91
    'iDoc.getElementById("rightScrollMenu").Click ' error 91
    
    With ie
    '.Stop
    '.Quit
    End With
    
    Set ie = Nothing: Set iDoc = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

The outerHTML is about 1600+ lines so I shortened it to this...

```
<div id="rightpanecontent">

<form name="MainForm" method="POST" action="PCMServlet" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="return false;" target="_self">

<!--************************************
    TAB VIEW
*************************************-->
<div id="tabsview_wrapper">
<div id="tabsandcontrols"> <!-- wrapper for tabs, dms, and tab actions -->

    <!--************************************
        TABS
    *************************************-->
<div id="leftScroll" style="display: none; left: 129px; top: 174px;">
<div id="rightScroll" style="display: none; left: 528px; top: 174px;">
<img id="rightScrollImg" src="/Agile/static/6dbe07cad9d304865dea9dfd18d4cb59/images/icn_action_tabscroll_right_enabled.png" onmousedown="scrollButtonPressed(event, 'right')" onmouseup="hideShowScrollButtons()" oncontextmenu="return false" style="cursor: pointer;">
</div>

<div id="rightScrollMenu" style="display: block; left: 891px; top: 142px;">
<img id="rightMenuImg" src="/Agile/static/8913d52dc8a2aeaaa1ea83e36663943d/images/icn_action_tabmenu.png" onclick="showTabsMenu(this, '21', event)" ondblclick="showTabsMenu(this, '21', event)" style="cursor: pointer;">
</div>
```

I have attempted a slew of coding variations.  Fire, click, nesting, focus, etc and I'm at my end.

agile screen capture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eureka moment...

```
    Dim sJS As String
    sJS = "javascript:displayObject" & _
           "('ItemHandler', '10000', '394341431', '12','', '0');"

        Call iDoc.parentWindow.execScript(sJS)
```